# Collections.sort isn't working

Tags: java, arrays, collections

```
public void sortByLastName(){
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Person>() {
        public int compare(Person p1, Person p2){
            return p1.getLastName().compareTo(p2.getLastName());
        }
    } );
}
```

The code shown here is part of a contactList array where i'm sorting out the list by last name, I can't seem to get it to compile, and I don't see what's wrong.

EDIT: The error on the compiler is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Person[], new Comparator<Person>(){})
at ContactList.sortByLastName(ContactList.java:34)
at Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Comment: Didn't compiler tell you what's wrong exactly?

Comment: Could you give us the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your list is an array, you're going to want to sort using Arrays.sort rather than Collections.sort.

Answer (score 1):

> sort(List, Comparator) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Person[], new Comparator(){})

This is telling you that the method `Collections.sort()`, which takes a `List` and a `Comparator` doesn't match what you are handing in, which seems to be an array of `Person` objects (`Person[]`) and a `Comparator`. Arrays and Lists in Java may seem similar at first, but they are different. In order to sort an array of objects, use [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) instead.